# Will Redd always have at least one real piece of art?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Redd has turned up in my town for the first time.

I eagerly went in, and... I'm pretty sure they're all fakes.

Does he ever have all fakes?  Is it worth buying on of the ones I'm less sure of being a fake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience with 4 Redd visits so far (and coroborated by several friends' Redd visits), Redd will always have *one* real item and 3 fakes. This makes it a puzzle to find which one is the real one, and means that if you've bought a real one, it's probably not worth it for your friends to check out Redd's.

Answer (score 2):

Actually today Redd has 2 pieces of real art! The worthy painting (which is never fake) and the motherly statute (the correct one with 2 children)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or some other way of confirming this?

Answer (score -1):

He does sell real pieces of art but it's a risk a person has to take.

From the Wikipedia of *crazy red*

The shop also sells paintings **which can be forgeries** - these can be identified by *Blathers*, or when you try to sell one to *Tom Nook*. If it is identified as a fake the name of the painting will change to Forged Painting. The shop is the only place (except for two paintings at Nook's) that sells paintings, but due to their unpredictable nature and high cost, there is a risk.

[This is a small guide I found on the interweb to show some differences in diagnosing if a painting is real or not.](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/paintings-works-of-art/)

But in the end if you can't see the difference, there is a chance still that all things Redd sells that week are fake.

I don't know if it shows all the painting he sells as I haven't played the new *Animal Crossing*

Comment: I may not have been clear enough about the question: I've found that guide, or a similar one, and compared it to determine the fakes.  The thing is, some of the differences are pretty hard to spot in the low resolution, so I'm wondering whether there are cases where *all* his stock is fake, so I don't keep looking for a 'real' piece of art.

Comment: That is possible. It is hard to determine if he will always have a real piece of art or not. It's a risk one has to take for the low prices. I'll keep researching the game as I have a interest in it. I'll ask a friend also who is a expert in this game. So I should have a more solid answer soon.

Comment: Ok, from more searching around, sadly yes. All things in Redds can be fake. I guess that's the risk you have to take for the low prices he sells the out. Hope I was of help.

Answer (score -1):

Today I just got Redd, and they were all fakes, so yes sometimes he will come by with fakes.

My artworks were:
Whistful with star earing
Mona lisa with eyebrows
The milkmaid with a lot of water flowing
the motherly statue with tongue out.

-these are all the signs that they were fake so I didn't have any real I could buy.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Kaitlyn, just checking - are you playing New Leaf, or New Horizons?  This question was about New Leaf.

Answer (score -2):

I have been to redd's at least 4 times before and every day there has been at least 1 real one but today i had all fakes. I checked the faqs and every painting or sculpture i had today were fake. I believe this has a very slim chance of happening but the bottom line is it still did.